# UWP Windows-10: How to use Thread Local Storage api's in Store apps

Tags: c++, windows-10-universal, c++-cx, thread-local-storage, wack

I have a C# app targeting Windows-10 Desktop & Mobile platforms. My app calls in to Windows Runtime Component written in C++ with c++/cx bindings. 

 My C++ code uses Thread Local Storage api's like ***TlsAlloc***, ***TlsGetValue***, ***TlsSetValue*** and ***TlsFree***.
When I run Windows App Certification Kit Tests (WACK tests), it complains about unavailability of these api, in the store app's.

> ◦API TlsAlloc in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application
>   type. sample.dll calls this API. 
> ◦API TlsFree in kernel32.dll is not
>   supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API. 
> ◦API
>   TlsGetValue in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application
>   type. sample.dll calls this API.
>  ◦API TlsSetValue in kernel32.dll is
>   not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.

I couldnt see alternatives for these api's for Windows-10 store app's. This [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686801(v=vs.85).aspx)
only talks about these api's availability on **Windows Phone 8**. I couldnt find any specific info regarding these api's for **Windows-10**

I am compiling my native C++ libs using **-DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_APP** flag

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: Be sure to keep WACK updated, this has changed with every SDK release.  If you want a clean report then [use FlsAlloc instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27979758/17034) like the UCRT does.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant, Thanks for the response. When you suggest to use FlsAlloc, does that mean, in my code, I need to change all calls to TlsAlloc into FlsAlloc or is there a macro setting which can do this trick for me. The [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686801(v=vs.85).aspx) says that "**When a Windows Phone Store app calls this function it is replaced with an inline call to FlsAlloc**". Does this replacement trickery happen with Windows-10? or is this only limited to WinPhone-8?

Comment: SDK v10 allows TlsAlloc() to be used by any UWP app.  Which is why you need to make sure that you have an up-to-date WACK.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant, Thanks for the response, I update my WACK tool. I now have version: **10.0.14393.33**. After the update though, when I select **Validate Store App** option from the WACK tool, it doesnt seem to find the app installed on my machine. My app is installed on the machine & I can see it in **Start Menu -> All apps**. WACK tool was able to find my app installed on the machine prior to this update. Has anything changes in the WACK tool in this update?

Comment: Hi @HansPassant, Since **Validate Store App** option was not working out, I tried to create an app package, but I am hitting this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856582/uwp-unable-to-register-app-for-windows-store-release. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Off topic, but is there any reason to use this over `thread_local`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HansPassant answer helped to figure this out.

Thread Local Storage(TLS) api's are supported in UWP Windows-10 Store apps. 

I had to upgrade to Windows SDK version **10.0.14393.33** 

Any version prior to this will error out on TLS api's

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 Phone UWP apps, the documentation appears to be wrong. You can use the Tls* functions if you link to kernel32.lib, but when you try to deploy it, it fails with a missing DLL error.

Instead, if you are linking to existing code that uses TLS, you can use the following emulation (put it anywhere in your code):

```
extern "C" {
DWORD WINAPI __imp_TlsAlloc() {
    return FlsAlloc(nullptr);
}
BOOL WINAPI __imp_TlsFree(DWORD index) {
    return FlsFree(index);
}
BOOL WINAPI __imp_TlsSetValue(DWORD dwTlsIndex, LPVOID lpTlsValue) {
    return FlsSetValue(dwTlsIndex, lpTlsValue);
}
LPVOID WINAPI __imp_TlsGetValue(DWORD dwTlsIndex) {
    return FlsGetValue(dwTlsIndex);
}
}
```