# UWP Unable to register app for Windows Store release

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, c++-cx, wack

I have a C# app targeting UWP Desktop & Mobile platforms. I want to run WACK tests prior to submitting app to store. I am trying to create app package by following the steps mentioned in this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454036.aspx)

When ever I try  to reserve a name for my app, I am getting the following error:

> **An unexpected error occurred when attempting to reserve the app name**

[image] 
Since the error info is not very useful, I am clueless as to what is going wrong.

I tried with several different name but every time I get the same error.

 I do not thing there is any issue with my account as I am able to login using my credentials as I see this message in VS-2015: "**You are signed into Windows Store as xxx@yyy.com**"
This is a business account. Several members of my team use this common account to register new apps on behalf of the company.

I have checked this [MSDN Forum page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1c268414-dab0-4d99-bf83-33367f2f2831/an-unexpected-error-occurred-when-attempting-to-reserve-the-app-name?forum=windowsstore). I followed steps mentioned in the solution, unfortunately [Microsoft Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/Disambiguation?ru=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.dev.microsoft.com%2F) doesnt seem to recognize my account **xxx@yyy.com**

Comment: did you ever solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When ever I try to reserve a name for my app, I am getting the following error:
>   **An unexpected error occurred when attempting to reserve the app name**

You will get this error when the name you are preserving has been reserved by someone.

According to first paragraph of [Create your app by reserving a name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/publish/create-your-app-by-reserving-a-name?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#new_name):

> Each reserved name must be unique throughout the entire Store.

You can check the availability of your app name by:

Logging in to [DashBoard](https://developer.microsoft.com/dashboard/overview)->Create a new App->Check availability.

Comment: even if I put ridiculuously-long names, I still get the error **An unexpected error occurred when attempting to reserve the app name** so I'm sure it doesn't mean that the name is reserved

Comment: also when I click on your dashboard link and log-in, it seems they want me to make a payment to register first? really? do I have to pay to publish something on the UWP store?

Comment: ditto, in 2021, this publishing process is still ridiculously difficult to understand. I have spent so many days still can't publish the app, WTF, why did they make publishing an app so hard? I hate every minute of it!