# UWP an unexpected error occured when attempting to reserve the app name

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to create a Microsoft store page for my companies UWP App. to do this I created a Microsoft partner center account for my company and a Microsoft developer account and got both authorized by Microsoft. Next i have been trying to reserve my app name and receiving the error "An unexpected error occurred when attempting to reserve the app name." in visual studio. no matter what I put in there I receive the same error.

When i look into this error the closest link I ever find is this [UWP Unable to register app for Windows Store release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856582/uwp-unable-to-register-app-for-windows-store-release)
which describes my issue perfectly however I run into a problem on the solution where when I click Create a new app it seems to kick me back to the main dashboard with no error message or prompt.

I'm not sure if I'm missing some sort of sign up or program for the partner center currently on the dash board the only program it says I am registered and able to access is "Commercial Marketplace". If anyone has any suggestions on what to try next I would greatly appreciate it.

Edit: I've been going through  support threads for a while. so far the theory is that my partner center account isn't correctly setup to interact with the Microsoft store. I'm attempting to sign up for a could additional programs but now I'm waiting on my it team to make me a global admin in office 365 as you need to be one in order to add programs ( being an admin in the partner center does not seem to be enough)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a new app in the [Partner Center Dashboard](https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/home) directly instead using Visual Studio. Here is the document:[Create your app by reserving a name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/create-your-app-by-reserving-a-name)

Comment: That was my thought to but when i go to do that clicking the create an app button seems to load the correct page then redirect then redirect me again to the dashboard :/. im currently trying to go through Microsoft support but I'm not in the right department so they are shuffling me around at the moment.

Comment: You might need to wait for a little bit until the support team contacts you. If you want to re-open a free [support ticket](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support), choose to Contact us, select Dashboard for Topic, and select App submission and management for issue type.